# Special Char '#' is creating issue in struts validator

Tags: java, struts2

I have created one simple form in jsp

```
<table class="entry">
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">
            <s:text name="location.label.country"/>
        </th>
        <td width="70%">
            <s:select list="@com.dmainc.commons.stuff.geo.StateUtils@getFormattedCountries()" headerKey="" headerValue="[Please Select]" listKey="abbreviation" listValue="prettyName" name="location.country" id="country_%{tabId}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <s:text name="location.label.address1"/>
        </th>
        <td>
            <s:textfield cssStyle="width: 19em" name="location.address1" id="address1_%{tabId}" cssClass="full"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I am using struts validator to validate the fields.
so whenever I put something with symbol # in address1(e.g. Test#) text box , validator throws NullPointerException on country field. also it trims # from the address 1 field.
It works fine with other symbols.
Is there any charset issue?
Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated

Edit:
Validator:

```
   @Override
   public void validate()
   {
      if(location.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("US"))
      {
         addFieldError("country", "State & Country mismatch!");
         addFieldError("state", "State & Country mismatch!");
      }
   }
```

Getting null pointer in if block

Update: complete jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<s:action namespace="/org" name="list_all" var="ol" />
<s:form id="edit_location_%{tabId}">
<s:hidden name="location.locationId" id="locationId_%{tabId}"/>
<s:hidden name="changeOrder.changeOrderId" id="changeOrderId"/>
<s:hidden name="parentChangeOrderId" id="parentChangeOrderId_%{tabId}"/>
<s:hidden name="requiresEndDating" id="requires_end_dating_%{tabId}"/>
<s:hidden name="updateEffectiveDate" id="update_effective_date_%{tabId}"/>
<div id="location_<s:property value='tabId'/>">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#general_<s:property value='tabId'/>"><s:text name="location.tab.general-info"/></a></li>
      <s:if test="showDetailsTab == true">
        <li><a href="#detail_<s:property value='tabId'/>"><s:text name="location.tab.details"/></a></li>
      </s:if>
      <s:if test="outputAdapters.size > 0">
        <li><a href="#outputadapter_<s:property value='tabId'/>"><s:text name="location.tab.outputadapters"/></a></li>
      </s:if>
   </ul>
       <div>
      <div id="general_<s:property value='tabId'/>">
           <div>
              <table class="placeholder" style="width: 100%">
                <tr>

                    <td style="width: 50%;">
                      <div class="field_maintain_div">
                         <fieldset class="field_maintain_fieldset">
                            <legend><s:text name="location.heading.address-info"/></legend>

                            <table class="entry">
                               <tr>
                                  <th width="30%"><s:text name="location.label.country"/></th>
                                  <td width="70%"><s:select list="@com.dmainc.commons.stuff.geo.StateUtils@getFormattedCountries()" headerKey="" headerValue="[Please Select]" listKey="abbreviation" listValue="prettyName" name="location.country" id="country_%{tabId}"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.address1"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield cssStyle="width: 19em" name="location.address1" id="address1_%{tabId}" cssClass="full"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.address2"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield cssStyle="width: 19em" name="location.address2" id="address2_%{tabId}" cssClass="full"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.city"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield cssStyle="width: 19em" name="location.city" id="city_%{tabId}" cssClass="half"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.state"/></th>
                                  <td><s:select list="@com.dmainc.commons.stuff.geo.StateUtils@STATES_PROVINCES" headerKey="" headerValue="[Please Select]" listKey="abbreviation" listValue="prettyName" name="location.state" id="state_%{tabId}"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.postal-code"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield cssStyle="width: 6em" name="location.zip" id="zip_%{tabId}"/></td>
                               </tr>
                            <tr>
                               <th><s:text name="location.label.county"/></th>
                               <td><s:textfield cssStyle="width: 19em" name="location.county" id="county_%{tabId}" cssClass="half"/></td>
                            </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.jurisdiction-code"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield name="location.jurisdictionCode" id="jurisdictionCode_%{tabId}" disabled="true"/></td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th><s:text name="location.label.compliance-jurisdiction-code"/></th>
                                  <td><s:textfield name="location.complianceJurisdictionCode" id="complianceJurisdictionCode_%{tabId}" /></td>
                               </tr>
                            </table>
                         </fieldset>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Can you add your struts validator definition?

Comment: added the validator code

Comment: it's not a validaor for address1

Comment: but when I inspect the location object, I am not getting # char in address1 and also country selected is null so its throwing null pointer exception,but when I remove the # from address1 , I am getting country selected

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over.

Comment: I can not see any `s:submit` inside `s:form`. How do you post form to the action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts text box removes # character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080115/struts-text-box-removes-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got resolved by replacing # with %23 in javascript.

```
address1 = address1.replace("#","%23");
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a keyword using by OGNL. Try escaping it by `\#`

Comment: Should I try to escape in jsp text box field? because in java Action class # is already get trimmed before I put any escape check.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your issue and thought you're going to hard code `#` in your jsp. But `#` is in your posted value. Please let me some time to check.

Comment: OK I tested struts and had not any issue with `#` to post it via a text field. How do you post it? via a form or query string? if you create query string yourself you should escape `#` with `%23`

Comment: I am submitting using struts form<s:form> and when I inspect the address in  action validator method it automatically trims all char after # also other bean variable become null.

Comment: Could you update your question with that `<s:form>` and inner text exactly?

Comment: Posted my complete jsp page.

Comment: I am still stuck in this issue, can anyone help me?

Comment: 3 days ago I commented on your question. please read. It's on your question.